# Loading Config.groovy in a Grails Script

Tags: grails

How do I get the values of Config.groovy in a Grails Script? I can get the values in BuildConfig.groovy by including the _GrailsSettings script.
Is it possible to get the values in Config.groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include _GrailsPackage script:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsPackage")
```

More information is [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/03/grails-goodness-access-configuration-in.html).

Comment: That worked, but the most important thing is you need to do      depends(compile,createConfig) and not just createConfig.